# is tensorflow.train.threading.Thread no longer supported?

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow

I am playing with the code from https://github.com/Russell91/TensorBox But it's failing to run with GPU, here the results of the run

```
TensorBox$ python train.py --hypes hypes/overfeat_rezoom.json --gpu 0 --logdir output
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro M4000
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.7725
pciBusID 0000:02:00.0
Total memory: 7.93GiB
Free memory: 7.63GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro M4000, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 537, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 534, in main
    train(H, test_images=[])
  File "train.py", line 457, in train
    t = tf.train.threading.Thread(target=thread_loop,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'threading'
```

Did tensorflow change the way it handles threads? Otherwise, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Change it to `threading.Thread`.

The import `tensorflow.train.threading.Thread` was never *officially* part of the API, but rather it was accessible because we weren't cautious about what symbols were visible through the `TensorFlow` module. As we move towards a stable release, we're clamping down on such undocumented inclusions, by using techniques like Python's `__all__` to define the precise contents of modules.